# Pure CSS hide/show div, don't hide when clicking on the div

Tags: css

I use this to hide and show a DIV, but instead of going to the location of the link it just hides the div when I press the link. The location shows up when I hover over the link, but when I click it it don't go there it just closes the element.

```
#cont {display: none; }
.show:focus + .hide {display: inline; }
.show:focus + .hide + #cont {display: block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ekon6wfb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the element is hidden when `:focus` is removed from the `.show` element.

To work around this, you could also show the element when hovering over it:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/rdp68egu/)

```css
.show:focus ~ #cont,
#cont:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
#cont {
  display: none;
}
.show:focus + .hide {
  display: inline;
}
.show:focus ~ #cont,
#cont:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#show" class="show">[Show]</a>
<a href="#hide" class="hide">/ [Hide]</a>
<div id="cont">
  <a href="/test">Go Here</a>
</div>
```